# saving a plotly and 3d images in a HTMl format in mylocal drive

Tags: python, html, plotly, data-visualization

I am trying to save plotly images generated (code 2 below) and 3d images in a HTML format (code 1 below) in my local drive but I get the following error and not able to proceed further. Could you please help me?

Error: ***The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure***

Code:

```
tsne_3d_df['normalized_kmeans'] = normalized_kmeans.labels_
fig = plot_3d(tsne_3d_df, name='normalized_kmeans')

# htmkl file
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='lifeExp.html')
```

Code 2:

```
def PlotPie(df, nameOfFeature):
    labels = [str(df[nameOfFeature].unique()[i]) for i in range(df[nameOfFeature].nunique())]
    values = [df[nameOfFeature].value_counts()[i] for i in range(df[nameOfFeature].nunique())]

    trace=go.Pie(labels=labels,values=values)

    py.iplot([trace])
fig = PlotPie(df, Target)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='lifeExp.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to get figure, you should do:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels,values=values)])
```

and just plot it after

```
fig.show()
```

I would like to point out that your `PlotPie` function has no return value, so the assignment to fig will fail, use `return fig` or just save file within the function. You should not use offline in new versions, use `fig.write_image("path/to/img.png")`.